# Unable to deploy application with Visual Basic Power Packs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I include the power packs in my app, and now I encounter problems when I try to deploy it to some other Win-XP machines which do not have Visual Studio (2008), although I include its DLL inside the installation package.

The DLL is "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Visual Basic Power Packs\1.1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll" and I'm just copying it into the installation path.

What am I missed?

Please see the errors that I got:
http://gomidjets.com/cc.JPG
http://gomidjets.com/ccerror.JPG

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy the power pak dll as it has some dependencies. You need to make sure that you use a setup or deployment project to distribute your application.

If you are using Power Pak 2.0 then you want to look at the readme file [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/f/b/1fbba5cb-53d2-4bcd-862c-b91d4122cd63/Visual_Basic_2005_PowerPacks_2_Readme.htm#Deployment_Issues)

From looking inside the install files looks like the Power Paks uses the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

So to recap , you want to publish an application. So you click build in the toolbar and publish. After you have followed the wizard the error means that you cannot run the program on any other machine which doesent't have visual studio?

Are you using the free (express) edition? If so , I don't think the edition you have allows you to publish to any other computers except the ones with visual studio. I tried to install one of my programs on a non-visual-studio-computer and it didnt work...

If you have the trial version , I can't really help you...